# Generate a crosstab with the means of two dataframes columns

Tags: r, crosstab

I have two dataframes, one called "students.short", generate by:

```
students.short <- data.frame(shoesize=c(38,39,38,38,39,38,37,36),
 population=c("kuopio","kuopio","kuopio","tampere",
 "tampere","tampere","tampere","tampere"))

students.short

  shoesize population
1       38     kuopio
2       39     kuopio
3       38     kuopio
4       38     kuopio
5       39    tampere
6       38    tampere
7       37    tampere
8       36    tampere
```

and the other called "students.tall":

```
students.tall <- data.frame(shoesize=c(44,42,43,43,42,44,43,43),
 population=c("kuopio","kuopio","kuopio","kuopio",
 "tampere","tampere","tampere","tampere"))

students.tall

  shoesize population
1       44     kuopio
2       42     kuopio
3       43     kuopio
4       43     kuopio
5       42    tampere
6       44    tampere
7       43    tampere
8       43    tampere
```

and I need to create a crosstab between the population (kuopio or tampere) and the means of the shoesize of each dataframes like

```
                       kuopio   tampere

studenst.short          38.3       37.6

studenst.tall             43         43
```

I can't find a clean or easy way to do that, any idea or any help, please?

Comment: Please present your data using `dput`. It makes it easier to import your data into R, and improves your chances for a great answer

Comment: what is kuopio and tampere?...Just for reference :)

Comment: @Sotos, I think they're towns in Finlad?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Wimpel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one go, using `data.table`

- first, create a named list of the data.tables (using `setDT()` )
- then, bind the lists together (using `rbindlist()`, using the names as an id (`idcol = TRUE`).
- last, `dcast` to wide format, summarising with `mean` of the `value.var`;
  `shoesize`

**code**

```
library( data.table )

dcast( rbindlist( list( students.short = setDT( students.short ), 
                        students.tall = setDT( students.tall ) ),
                  idcol = TRUE ),
       .id ~ population, 
       value.var = "shoesize", 
       fun = mean )

#               .id   kuopio tampere
# 1: students.short 38.33333    37.6
# 2:  students.tall 43.00000    43.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best answer - understood as a mixture of elegant simplicity and efficiency - that could be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` driven answer. We basically bind the two data frames first using the `.id` argument to differentiate between the data frames. We then `group_by` the `.id` and `population` and calculate the mean, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = 'group') %>% 
       group_by(group, population) %>% 
       summarise(new = mean(shoesize))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   group [?]
>   group population   new
>   <chr> <fct>      <dbl>
> 1 1     kuopio      38.3
> 2 1     tampere     37.6
> 3 2     kuopio      43  
> 4 2     tampere     43
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Combine your data frames using `rbind()` first:

```
df <- rbind(studnets.short, students.tall)
df$height_cat <- rep(c("short", "tall"), # create categorical height variable
   c(nrow(students.short), nrow(students.tall)))
```

Then use `tapply()`. For this mock data frame, it works like this:

```
df <- data.frame(size = round(rnorm(30, 39, 2)),
                 pop = sample(c("kuopio", "tampere"), 30, replace = T),
                 height = sample(c("short", "tall"), 30, replace = T))
tapply(df$size, INDEX = df[c(3, 2)], mean, na.rm=T)
# df[c(3, 2)] refers to height and pop columns of df respectively

       pop
height  kuopio  tampere
  short     39 39.57143
  tall      41 39.22222
```